# CryptoException while decrypting in AEM

Tags: aem

we are facing CryptoException  while decrypting the text in AEM 6.0 version.  Actually one of our environment is having this issue. we dont have this issue in other environments. This issue is specific to only one environment.  Literally we tried all the options.

Tried options:-
Deleted /etc/key folder in publish server and restarted Adobe Granite Crypto Bundle and restarted pub server too. But nothing is helped and still facing the same error.

Below is complete error message

```
Caused by: com.adobe.granite.crypto.CryptoException: Cannot convert byte data
    at com.adobe.granite.crypto.internal.CryptoSupportImpl.unprotect(CryptoSupportImpl.java:160)
    at com.pearson.aem.aemcore.hybris.services.CommerceServiceImpl.getExternalUser(CommerceServiceImpl.java:326)
    ... 136 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.adobe.granite.crypto.CryptoException: Failed decrypting cipher text
    at com.adobe.granite.crypto.internal.CryptoSupportImpl.decrypt(CryptoSupportImpl.java:96)
    at com.adobe.granite.crypto.internal.CryptoSupportImpl.unprotect(CryptoSupportImpl.java:157)
    ... 137 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.rsa.jsafe.JSAFE_PaddingException: Invalid padding.
    at com.rsa.jsafe.JSAFE_SymmetricCipher.decryptFinal(Unknown Source)
    at com.adobe.granite.crypto.internal.jsafe.JSafeCryptoSupport.getPlainText(JSafeCryptoSupport.java:326)
    at com.adobe.granite.crypto.internal.jsafe.JSafeCryptoSupport.getPlainText(JSafeCryptoSupport.java:308)
    at com.adobe.granite.crypto.internal.CryptoSupportImpl.decrypt(CryptoSupportImpl.java:94)
    ... 138 common frames omitted
```

Is there any config which we should cross verify?

Comment: With some release the hmac and the master key where moved to the filesystem. It is somewhere below the bundles folder.

Comment: But PaddingException sounds like a very differently configured JDK. AEM uses the JDK encryption features without much AEM stuff around it. And the encryption stuff can be heavily customized and configured in the JDK.